# Not able to see IIS home page for the newly created Azure Machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created Virtual Machine in Azure and able to take RDP successfuly

After that I have added IIS service in that machine and able to see IIS home page inside the machine (http://localhost/iisstart.htm)

But in the outside the VM(over the internet)-http:///iisstart.htm,I  can't able to access IIS home page

telnet  80 -- >working fine

ping   getting request timed out.

Please advise anything needs to be configured in Azure Portal.

Comment: Ping isn't supported from external sources, so you won't get ping responses. If you can telnet to port 80 and receive content, this means your port has been opened correctly (via endpoints or network security rules). Not much else to go on, with what you provided. Maybe edit your question with more details?

Comment: Did you setup endpoints for HTTP? What kind of VMs are you creating VM (Resource Manager) or VM (Classic)?

Answer (score 0):

Can be one of the reason:

1. Often - endpoints problem. Add endpoints for 80 and 443 ports to the
   VM on the Azure portal.
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/
2. Often - address problem. Can you try to access your VM using IP
   address? But do not rely on the IP address as it will change until
   you set up the static one. You can try to go to your VM using
   cloudapp.net subdomain your VM is running in.

   And, if your project can be used in such mode, try to look into
   Azure WebApp as it is a lot easier to manage and have a lot of the
   same functionality.
3. Extremely rare - platform networking issue. Re-creation of the VM
   can solve the problem. In a few years, i had that issue once.